# How to compute cohomology of $C^0(S^n,X)$?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

While there are many approaches to the (singular) cohomology of free loop spaces $LX=C^0(S^1,X)$ in the literature, I can't find many results about the cohomology of the mapping spaces $C^0(S^n,X)$ for $n>1$, that do not require a deep understanding of homotopy theory (and its notations). In particular, I would like to know $H^*(C^0(S^n,S^{m});\mathbb{Q})$, where $m>n>1$, but can't find any explicit results on these cohomology groups. Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, knowing $H^0$ for arbitrary $m$ and $n$ means you know the cardinality of all the homotopy groups of spheres, so you can't expect anything too explicit...

Comment: You can study the Serre spectral sequence of the evaluation fibration $\Omega^n X\rightarrow C^0(S^n,X)\xrightarrow{e} X$. This is about the best approach you can hope for in general. Of course you have to know $H^*X$ and $H^*\Omega^nX$, even before computing the differentials in the SS. There are many techniques for computing $H^*\Omega^nX$, but these would probably classify as 'deeper results'.

Comment: Hi Stephan! There are some papers by Brown--Szczarba and Vigue-Poirier which describe the minimal model (in the sense of rational homotopy theory) of $C^0(X,Y)$ in terms of those of $X$ and $Y$ under certain conditions (which are certianly satisfied for $X=S^n$ and $Y=S^m$). This gives a DGA whose cohomology is $H^*(C^0(S^n,S^m);\mathbb{Q})$. I haven't seen any computations of the cohomology in such simple examples, but for spheres I beleive it should be tractable.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments!